# php dynamically get the count for a specific word in a webpage

Tags: php, count

I have a webpage, where on search of a product, gives the matched products list.

Below each product has a word which says `Read me`.

I need to get the **count** of this word `Read me`.

For example, on search of some product string,  if i get 10 results of products, 10 products has `Read me` word below them and my count should be 10.

If the searched result is 4 (ie 4 times `Read me`), my count should be 4.

**UPDATE:**

```
$text2 = 'Read me';
$text2 = strtolower($text2);
echo substr_count($text2, 'read me');
```

**UPDATE:**

My string `Read Me` comes from html like below dynamically:

```
<div class="blog-article-description">
    ...
    <a href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>" class="blog-article-link">Read me</a>
</div>
```

From using the suggested code, it echo's `1` above each products, which is logically correct, but i need the count of total occurrences in the page

Comment: Nope, just as expected it returns 1. https://3v4l.org/HoQCf

Comment: You're checking how many times `$text2` is inside `$text2`?

Comment: `$text2 = 'Read Me';` should be greater than searched string

Comment: Hi @Andreas, yes it returns 1 if i run it separately, if i use them in my project, i need to get the count of that word dynamically.

Comment: I just want to get the count of my word `Read me` based on the number of products displayed , if 3 products, then count is 3 @FedericoklezCulloca, so basically on page load, it should search the entire page with that word and display the count

Comment: @user7115281 are you sure the content of the page has 'Read me' and not 'Read Me' or 'read me'?

Comment: Yes it has exactly 'Read me'

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php Can also count right? Is it faster or not?

Comment: @Rustyjim why would it be faster since it does more than just count? Also, why do something completely unrelated to your objective?

Comment: Sry for being lightly related , was just wondering if it was a trick to replace same with same thing and count it. It does more you're right.

Comment: @user7115281 What is $text2. in your example it's just "read me". But in reality? Is it a file_get_contents() or what? Include the real code instead. Your example is probably not close to the real code. If it is, it's wrong.

Comment: @user7115281 Did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to find exact matches the substr_count is extremly fast.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php#119199

But if you need to find both `Read me`, `read me` and `Read Me` then regex is probably a better option.

This searches for $find case insensitiv and returns the matches to $m. 
Count finds the count of matches.
If we use array_count_values on $m[0] we get the count of each type of spelling of the word(s).

```
$text2 = "Read me .... Read Me, READ ME. REad ME read me Read me read me READ ME rEAd me";
$find = "read me";


preg_match_all("/" . $find . "/i", $text2, $m);
echo count($m[0]) . "\n";
var_dump(array_count_values($m[0]));
```

Output:

```
9 // the count()
array(6) {
  ["Read me"] => 2
  ["Read Me"] => 1
  ["READ ME"] => 2
  ["REad ME"] => 1
  ["read me"] => 2
  ["rEAd me"] => 1
}
```

https://3v4l.org/iSHlL

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
$text2 =  'Read me, This is curious topic. Please Read Me';
$text2 = strtolower($text2);
echo substr_count($text2, 'read me');
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: Convert  `$text2 = strtolower($text2);` to lower case as I did.

Comment: Hi @GufranHasan, have updated the question, it shows 1 above each product, but how to get the total occurrences in the entire page

Comment: Please put it in loop

Answer (score -1):

With [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) could do something that you want:

```
// A string with the several lines and 5 Read me
$a = 'aaaaaaaaa
bbbb Read Me ccccc Read Mee dddddd
Read Me Read Me Read Me
eeeeeeeeeee';

preg_match_all('/Read Me/', $a, $m);

print(count($m[0]));
```